# Where is the Apple Air Port Utility 'Use dynamic global hostname' option?

Tags: airport

I just can't find the "Use dynamic global hostname" option in Apple Air Port Utility 6.1 (610.31). Where can I find this option now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple seem to have removed/hidden some of the more advanced options from the Airport Utility interface in version 6 and this is likely one of them. Unless there's a workaround someone else can suggest to make such options visible again, on 10.7 (Lion), I've been getting around this by using the [AirPort Utility 5.6 for Mac OS X Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1482). You can find the Dynamic Global Hostname option by clicking Manual Setup > AirPort > Base Station tab > Edit - though I'm sure you already know that :)

Note that I have the [AirPort Express 802.11n (2nd Generation)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP651) and the Airport Utility 5.6 does complain that

> This version of AirPort Utility doesn't support this AirPort wireless
>   device and might improperly configure the device if you continue to
>   use it

when you try to configure it. It seems to read all the information correctly **but** I would urge you to export your configuration first and/or not have anything you can't put back after a full reset, if things go wrong.